# Word wrap on IE css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, nowrap

I tried to applied property "white-space:nowrap" to a span tag. It works well on all browser but in IE and Edge it breaks word. I have to show all my content in the same line.

I tried to set property "break-word: nowrap" but it not seems to work.

How can I resolve my problem with css?

Comment: It's supposed to work... I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/qrgtcj3b/) that works as expected. So, can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @SankarRaj break-word is what I tried to avoid.. I tried  "normal" but not work..

Answer (score 0):

It should be "white-space: **nowrap**" not "white-space: no-wrap".

Comment: I modified my question